# Error:4- Unable to start the virtual device

Tags: emulation, genymotion

When I run virtual device in `genymotion`, I get this error:

[image: Unable to start the virtual device]
How I can handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

that say your video card must be updated and with this current driver dont work, and you must be installed OpenGL and should be supported with on your video card

Comment: I know this, but how I can do this?

Comment: @Troy you can use DriverPackSolution for update Your video card or download updated driver from internet. then download openGL and install it